# Swift iOS Facebook SDK loop on login with safari view controller

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, safari, facebook-login

I'm trying to add login with facebook in iOS app written in swift.

the problem here is that when I fill the login proccess in SSFSafariViewController and click Done it re-opens the login dialog in SSFSafariViewController and keeps doing that for ever.

here is my code:

```
// Loads user data if he is logged in, othewise asks him to login
static func login(ViewController controller: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    // If user has logged in before: dont ask him to login again
    // use previus login data
    if(AccessToken.current != nil){
        // Load user data
        create();
        return true;
    }
    // If user is'nt logged in: ask him to login
    else {
        var result: Bool = false;
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .userFriends, .email], viewController: controller) { loginResult in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
                result = false;
            case .cancelled:
                result = false;
            case .success( _, _, _):
                result = true;
            }
        }

        // If user has logged in: laod his data
        if(result){
            create();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? can you update in your question?

Comment: from a viewcontroller in viewDidAppear, this function is in another class meant to handle the login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem, it looks like is was a problem with the delegate where `SSFSafariViewController` presented by Facebook SDK wasn't calling back! and the SDK Never got the result of the `SSFSafariViewController` so it was trying to resolve the problem by re-presenting the login view `SSFSafariViewController` and that what cased the loop over and over again.

so the solution was to add this function to AppDelegate:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue, annotation: UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation);
}
```

then every thing works out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can return value while you used closure inside the method . so you need to create function with closure as below :

**Note: you need to solve bracket error**

```
   func login(ViewController controller: UIViewController,  callback: (_ isResult: Bool) -> Void) -> Void {
      if(AccessToken.current != nil){
        // Load user data
            callback(true)
    }
    // If user is'nt logged in: ask him to login
    else {
        var result: Bool = false;
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .userFriends, .email], viewController: controller) { loginResult in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
                callback(false)
            case .cancelled:
               callback(false)
            case .success( _, _, _):
              callback(true)
            }
        }
   }
```

**Calling method**

```
self.login(ViewController: self) { (isResult) in
            // isResult your boolean
            if(isResult){
            create();
        }
      }
```

Comment: thank you, your answer really helped me control the flow of my app! but it wasn't the solution for the endless loop of 'SSFSafariViewController' presented by facebook. I have posted the solution, but after all i  replaced my version with yours. many thanks

Comment: and check url scheme for this issue.

Comment: when i started using your version i noticed that some values that where intended to set inside function create where nil inside the completion block of the login function when i call it inside viewDidLoad and only inside viewDidLoad. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5; Facebook SDK version: 13.2.0**

I had the same problem but only when I tried to log in via the Facebook app.

And for me, the author’s solution also solved the problem, but I had to update it nowadays.

So in the AppDelegate we should add this function:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
        if url.scheme?.hasPrefix("fb") == true { return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options) }
        // Handle other URL schemes here
        return false
    }
    
}
```